# Select list of node titles for a view exposed filter

Tags: views

I want to create an exposed filter based on the title of a node. How do I do this? I would prefer this filter be a select list - that is, all of the node names are listed based on the criteria I list.

So let's say you have three titles for events:

```
A Trip to the Woods

Go to the Beach

Off to the Farm
```

I would like the exposed filter to be a select list of these three nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Finder module](https://drupal.org/project/finder) in addition to creating a [View Page](https://drupal.org/project/views).

From the Finder module project description:

> Typically Finder is used for these purposes:
>
> - As a search tool to find a group of nodes or users.
> - As a way to navigate to a specific node or user page that matches criteria.
> - As an alternative to exposed filters for a Views module display.
>
> Specific example uses of Finder:
>
> - An autocomplete search on node titles in order to find a node.
> - **A select list of all the possible values for a particular content field
>     in order to get a list of corresponding nodes.**
> - Multiple groups of radio buttons and checkboxes with taxonomy terms to find nodes that match all the selected terms.
> - An autocomplete search on usernames in order to go to a user profile.
> - A multi-step wizard form to whittle down a pool of potential results by asking questions on one step that will reduce the possible answers on the next step.

Finder should be able to pick and choice, or filter, what shows up in the that Select list.

Comment: I have used the Finder module, but it's too difficult to configure and use and also with huge performance issue :).

Comment: Hrm, is there an easy tutorial for this? This does seem probably like what I want, but Bala is correct - it does seem fairly difficult to configure (I'm sure with some practice I can get it, but I'm on a deadline)

Comment: Does Finder support relationships like Views does? I'm trying to pull the associated node related to an entity called registration.

Answer (score -1):

[Views Autocomplete Filters](https://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters)

> - It works for node titles or cck text fields.
> - The autocomplete results are actually the view results, so they are view related.

Comment: This is just an autocomplete. I want a select list.